# ng command not recognized after installing angular-cli globally

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I tried to install angular/CLI via https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#!#index

I have installed node.js and npm (I have checked it by command line).

My problems started on second step. Command line can not recognize all commands with ng.

Comment: did you run this command `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: Yes @k11k2 is most likely right. You need to install @angular/cli globally. To do so is just as he said the npm command with the ` -g` option

Comment: It's quite possible that your path is set incorrectly, especially if you are using Windows. Do other globally installed packages run OK? Google for instructions on how to make sure globally-installed packages are on your path.

Answer (score 3):

Include  `%AppData%\npm` to your path variable.

How to include

1. Goto advanced system setting
2. Click environment variables
3. In the System Variables section select path variable and click edit
4. Click new and add `%AppData%\npm`. Then press Ok